# How to convert 2 DTO to 1 DTO mapstruct

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dto, mapstruct

How to convert `TestDTO` and `QuestionDTO` to `PageTestDTO` using mapstruct

I understand that this can be done quickly manually, but I would like to know this method

**PageTestDTO**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class PageTestDTO {
private List<TestDTO> testDTOList;
private List<QuestionDTO> questionDTOList;
private Pageable pageable;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public static class Pageable{
    private Integer totalPages;
    private Long totalElements;
    private Integer number;
}
```

**TestDTO**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class TestDTO {
private Long id;
private String name;
private List<QuestionDTO> questionList;

public TestDTO(Long id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
```

**QuestionDTO**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class QuestionDTO {
private Long id;
private String question;
private List<AnswerDTO> answersList = new ArrayList<>();

public QuestionDTO(Long id, String question){
    this.id = id;
    this.question = question;
}
```

Comment: Show the code that you've done so far

Comment: This is impossible. You don't have testDTOList.